# Trying to modify default pagination settings within public profile templates

Tags: pagination

Specifically, when a member is logged into their front-end profile templates, and you're viewing the messages in the inbox-folder. The pagination displays only 5 entries per page.

I've tried modifying some parameters in both of the following files:

- system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Pagination.php
- system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Pagination.php

But nothing seems to modify the results in any way. I also wouldn't mind just disabling the pagination altogether, since I use a fancy plugin for it anyways (mix_it_up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To win, you must smell the prey, feel the kill...

Really, though, you need to trace backwards through the internals of EE to actually find the core code you need to modify. In `/system/expressionengine/libraries/Messages.php:87`

```
var $per_page           = 5;                // Messages on a Folder's Page
```

But I never recommend modifying core code. But I'm not sure you have much other choice. If I were you, I'd throw together a quick extension, and `var_dump($this); die();` on this hook and see if you can just modify that value without modifying core code.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member/index.html

It really depends on your laziness factor for this task.

Comment: Thanks jrothafer! Figures I didn't see that. As it sits, I've already had to make a fair amount of changes to the Messages.php file anyways. (This is a rather niche site with some extensive needs).

However, I DO need to start wrapping my head around utilizing hooks into the site. So I'm going to give that a shot too, for some other aspects of the site.